# How to identify a particular select statement in multiquery mysqli and php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure which contains multiple `select` query in PHP. I am using `mysqli_multi_query` to call the procedure and I'm using `mysqli_store_result` to store the result of select query.

Question is that I want to identify the select query, which select query is getting the result, I want to tag it uniquely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra column to each query, like this:

```
select 'query_tag_1' as tag, ...
from your_table;

select 'query_tag_2' as tag, ...
from your_table;

select 'query_tag_3' as tag, ...
from your_table;
```

You can check the value of `tag` column from PHP.

**Update**: Another way would be to rename a column (the first for example):

```
select id as id_tag1, ...
from your_table;

select id as id_tag2, ...
from your_table;

select id as id_tag3, ...
from your_table;
```

Comment: This would add column to result set i dont want to add tag column in my resultant set because if have numbers of records in result set than an additional column containing same value, would be against DRY is there any other alternative without adding tag as column

Comment: @Bhavesh Added an other option related to column- name.